# How to register an instance to the ServiceCollection in ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I'm migrating my web app from ASP.NET Core RC1 to RC2. In RC2 the `IServiceCollection` doesn't have the `AddInstance` method anymore. How do I get the Configuration registered?

Here how it was done in RC1

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // AddInstance doesn't exist
        services.AddInstance<IConfiguration>(Configuration);        
        .
        .       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

try this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

I had same problem like you and I solved it with this.

Comment: Just in case anyone else, like me, find this works but wonders why, it's a simple API rename - https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/119 - I found @Thomas's comment fixed my problem, but since it's a security bit of code for me (adding the authorization handlers) I couldn't go on without figuring out why.